Error: The deploy step encountered an error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1 ❌
I want to utilise github action to build Unity projects in WebGL format so that they can be automatically deployed to github-pages.　To do this, I have created the following yml file.
name: Run the WebGL build
on:
  workflow_dispatch: {}
jobs:
  build:
    name: Run the WebGL build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Download the contents of the working directory Unity project using actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Check out my unity project.
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          lfs: true

      #Cache
      - name: Cache
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: Library
          key: Library-${{ hashFiles('Assets/**', 'Packages/**', 'ProjectSettings/**') }}
          restore-keys: |
            Library-
      
      # Free up disk space
      - name: Free Disk Space
        uses: jlumbroso/free-disk-space@main
        with:
          tool-cache: false
          
      # Using GameCI's Builder to perform a build of a Unity project
      - name: Run the WebGL build
        uses: game-ci/unity-builder@v4
        env:
          UNITY_LICENSE: ${{ secrets.UNITY_LICENSE }}
          UNITY_EMAIL: ${{ secrets.UNITY_EMAIL }}
          UNITY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.UNITY_PASSWORD }}
        with:
          targetPlatform: WebGL

          unityVersion: 2022.3.7f1
      # Deploying WebGL builds output by Builder to GitHub Pages
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        with:
          # GitHub Pages Specify the Orphan branch name for deployment
          branch: gh-pages

          # Specify the build folder path for deployment
          # GameCI's Builder outputs the build contents to the build folder by default
          folder: build

      # Make WebGL builds output by Builder available for download with artefacts
      - name: Upload the WebGL Build
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: Build
          path: build

Deploy to GitHub Pages, the following error occurs.
remote: error: Trace: a59363263caba1ca58255fda7ec1e3c13b86bd3ca8e2bf6810fde5aad40666d0        
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.        
remote: error: File WebGL/WebGL/Build/WebGL.data is 236.77 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB        
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.        
To https://github.com/(My repository)
 ! [remote rejected] github-pages-deploy-action/fmana2aw9 -> gh-pages (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/(My repository).git'
Running post deployment cleanup jobs… ️
/usr/bin/git checkout -B github-pages-deploy-action/fmana2aw9
Reset branch 'github-pages-deploy-action/fmana2aw9'
/usr/bin/chmod -R +rw github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder
/usr/bin/git worktree remove github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder --force
Error: The deploy step encountered an error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 1 ❌
Notice: Deployment failed! ❌

I believe that the WebGL.data built with Run the WebGL build is too large to deploy.
Using git-lfs as stated in the error text,I want to manage WebGL.data.
How can I utilise git-lfs with github actions?
